# Variable opacity in a scatter 3D plotly plot

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, density-plot, scatter3d

How to make a scatter3d look like a density plot in 3d?

I am trying to set the opacity (or some other variable) in a plot_ly scatter3d plot to use a value per point in the plot, with the values coming from a column in the dataframe. This in order to create a sort of 3d scatter density plot. 
In this case, the opacity column contains random values, but if this turns out to be possible, I want to make points LESS opaque when the amount of nearby points is high, and opaque when they are relatively isolated. 
Another approach to make this look like a density plot while perserving the scatter3d style is fine as well.

My attempts to play with opacity or alpha in the plot_ly code has failed and I could not find a working example.

The dataset can be downloaded from here: [file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmTMSwfWpWKXgRM0ZjDEF6ZpWCc2)

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(data.table)


mydf <- read.csv("myshowdf.csv")


ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput('scatter', width = 800, height = 600)  
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$scatter <- renderPlotly({
    ppl <- plot_ly(mydf, x = ~FL.Red.Range, y = ~FL.Yellow.Range, z = ~SWS.Length, mode = 'markers',
                   color = ~sub.flow.FP1,   marker = list(size = 4, opacity =mydf$opacity),
                   colors = c('blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow'),
                   type = 'scatter3d', source = 'scatter') %>%
      layout( autosize = F,
              margin = list(l = 40, r = 20, b = 20, t = 40, pad = 4)
      )
    ppl$elementId <- NULL
    ppl
  })
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: it should be downloadable through the onedrive link in the question Maximillian

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see the link :/

Comment: I think you cannot do that. From the documentation:
opacity (number between or equal to 0 and 1)
Sets the marker opacity. Note that the marker opacity for scatter3d traces must be a scalar value for performance reasons. To set a blending opacity value (i.e. which is not transparent), set "marker.color" to an rgba color and use its alpha channel. https://plot.ly/r/reference/

Comment: Possibly, I wasnt sure. Basically what I was looking for was to set a unique opacity or alpha value for each individual point

Comment: I tried passing a list of colors with different alpha values to markers but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Same conclusion as my trials then. As we say in Italy "va bo", or so be it. Thanks for trying maximiallian!

Comment: Let's continue in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/159787/plotly?tab=general

Comment: Ok maximillian, hope to chat to you soon there then.